# RegEx validation name with underscore

Tags: java, regex

I had a validation like, string can contains alphanumeric and _ in between.
String can start and end with _
string can be an _

I wrote RegEx

```
^(_)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?([a-zA-Z0-9])+?(_)?$
```

My Unit testes

```
    assertEquals(false, UtilityFunction.isAlphaNumeric("__"));
    assertEquals(true, UtilityFunction.isAlphaNumeric("a"));
    assertEquals(true, UtilityFunction.isAlphaNumeric("_a"));
    assertEquals(true, UtilityFunction.isAlphaNumeric("a_"));
    assertEquals(true, UtilityFunction.isAlphaNumeric("_a_"));
    assertEquals(true, UtilityFunction.isAlphaNumeric("_a_a"));
    assertEquals(true, UtilityFunction.isAlphaNumeric("_a_a"));
    assertEquals(false, UtilityFunction.isAlphaNumeric("_a__a"));
    assertEquals(true, UtilityFunction.isAlphaNumeric("_a_a_"));
    assertEquals(true, UtilityFunction.isAlphaNumeric("a_a"));
```

Getting failed at 
"_a_a"

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I initially suggested the same solution, but `__` is disallowed, it seems.

Comment: Your regex is *fixed* and checks for _ (0 or 1), number of character (0 or 1) and underscore(0 or1). `_a_a` doesn't match this format.

Comment: Show us what all are allowed. We could help you write a better regex.

Comment: The answer is perfect. It passed 26 asserts. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
^(?!.*?__)\w+$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lN6oY0/1)

Comment: In java it will be: `^(?!.*?__)\\w+$`